# Is there an Excel function to change a series of cells to specific numbers?

Tags: excel

Here is a sample of my data, ranging from A to E

```
A1          A2          P1          P2          P3
40.90066442 41.35447465 42.48572877 43.13421103 44.20111442
41.83816219 43.66191848 43.60708857 42.84394492 44.93688671
42.72782323 41.93720204 44.65360963 42.05375293 42.59821957
44.5014319  44.87152465 40.22132159 43.6461762  40.09663827
42.66126635 40.41060513 44.96104934 44.00995001 44.83892466
43.10426111 42.6889963  40.59397172 42.71873876 42.32698387
40.27160885 41.37592934 44.34740361 44.28278582 40.77164908
40.27472844 42.72533069 43.52493125 41.38676985 41.81313137
41.24130514 41.23524984 43.34977821 43.78923814 41.18174266
43.07302751 40.57295097 44.71487828 41.33976882 40.08119126
43.03435032 44.90969042 40.71444277 43.55353499 41.23095887
42.81947006 42.82444568 40.91557755 42.38148784 43.62205421
42.30369232 41.68249279 41.56371958 40.92479625 40.31827645
43.74059647 43.94346997 44.4068792  44.03304134 40.70393326
40.99133772 44.93606236 41.63518244 43.13233042 42.33633284
40.51979584 41.34221119 44.59555712 42.58423944 43.19678813
44.48192353 42.59459336 44.8567798  44.93942944 41.05657503
```

I want to change the cells to "0" and "1". So if the value is greater than or equal 42, the cell will receive a value of "1". If it is less than 42, the cell will get a value of "0". 
I struggle to find out a solution or a similar function to describe. Can anyone help?

Comment: To do in place this will require VBA.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  If you want to do this in another place then you can use a formula like: `=--(A2>=42)` in the first cell then copy over and down the same size as the data.

Comment: You could put the formula on another sheet, then just use *that* sheet for your reviewing/whatever.  (You could even copy/paste as Values to "lock" the data in).

Comment: Well that is a different question then what was posed.

Comment: Look up conditional formulas in Excel. It's totally possible to do what you need with those and it's well worth learning.

Comment: Please ask what you want not what you think will get you where you want to go.

Comment: But something like `=MATCH(A2,{1,20,43})-1` will answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per all the comments use:

```
=MATCH(A2,{1,20,43})-1
```

This will return the relative location in the number scheme and subtract one.

Comment: Thank you,@Scott

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to apply formulas in another set of columns:

```
=IF(A2>=42,1,0)
```

Then you can copy all those cells and paste them wherever you need with the "paste values" feature.

Comment: `=--(A2>=42)` is much shorter and as the OP has commented not what they are looking for.